# OpenGL - API design

Tags: c++, opengl, api-design

I've been working on my new opengl based rendering engine, and I ran into the following issue: I would like to expose opengl functionalities, like `glClear(); glUniformxx, ...` but I need the user to create an opengl context before calling any of those functions. The problem is that opengl **does not manage contexts for you**, and calling any gl functions before results in undefined behaviour(most of the time a **segfault**). So my question would be **How should I impose context creation before any openGL function calls ?**

- My first idea was to create a **singleton class** called GLFeatures, that would expose all openGL functionalities and only call them if it has been passed a valid context.

Comment: Most implementations use thread-local storage to manage the active context. You can layer your own solution on top of this. Wrap the window-system function to manage active contexts and then you'll always know whether there's an active context in the calling thread and you can nop stuff / issue whatever warnings/errors you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TOTALLY OPINION BASED**:

I'd suggest writing an entirely different class for OpenGL context management, this way you can switch between them for multi-window rendering. Your "GLFeatures" class can have a function called "SetCurrentContext", which sets a pointer to the context management class. You can still guard all functions from being called before the context is initialized by just asserting the context pointer at the beginning of each function.

However, just using the singleton for all of that should work as well, the above is just how I'd do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Do you think that wrapping all gl features in a singleton is considered as good design though ?

Comment: Is it better to handle states in separate classes like a Shader class , etc.. ?

Comment: Keep in mind that OpenGL is just a giant state machine under the surface. Adding some OOP-style abstraction can be helpful to manage these states, as it can get out of hand sometimes.

Comment: ok; thank you for helping me out :)